# Malformed output with scanf (Hacking: The Art of Exploitation Example)

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm currently reading the book "Hacking: The Art of Exploitation". I'm only in the beginning chapters right now, and it's going over some basic string copying and input functions in C.

The most recent example uses a combination of strcpy and scanf to repeatedly print a string, but when compiled, produces malformed output for me. The example is as follows:

**input.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char message[10];
    int count, i;

    strcpy(message, "Hello, world!");

    printf("Repeat how many times? ");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    for(i=0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%3d - %s\n", i, message);
}
```

According to the book, when you input a number, it should print that many times.

For example:

```
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ ./input
Repeat how many times? 3
0 - Hello, world!
1 - Hello, world!
2 - Hello, world!
```

This works for me, but somehow the "Hello, world!" string becomes corrupted and malformed and will only print "Hello, wor" and then print an incorrect character.

```
helpme@stackoverflow:~/booksrc $ ./input
Repeat how many times? 3
0 - Hello, wor
1 - Hello, wor␦
2 - Hello, wor␦
```

There seems to be some consistency to the incorrect characters printed on the end, as if it's iterating through UTF-8 characters or something similar. For the first three it will print the boxes that represent non-printable Unicode characters, and if given a much higher range, will eventually start printing real characters.

I think this has to do with the use of scanf and perhaps my terminal (I'm running this program on a Debian GNU/Linux box, using the default GNOME terminal.) But I'm curious how this example could have worked on previous versions of gcc and not the current version - is scanf interpreted differently on current versions of C?

As for additional information, I'm running gcc version 6.3.0.

If anyone could provide any assistance, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `char message[10];` This is small. It must be at least `char message[14];` or more.

Comment: Since you write out of bounds of the `message` array, you most likely write over the memory for the `count` and `i` variables. In turn, when you write to `count` and `i` you overwrite the data that was out of bounds, leading to the "incorrect" output.

Comment: Your `message` array isn't long enough to hold the string - `"Hello, world!"` is more than 10 characters long.  Make sure to allocate enough space to hold the entire string *plus* a 0-valued string terminator.

Comment: Now, if the point of the exercise is to show how writing past the end of a buffer can be used as an exploit, be aware that the exact behavior will depend on the data that's being overwritten - if you don't clobber anything important, the program will appear to function normally.

Comment: This is a C question. Please don't tag your question as C++, unless your question is somehow relevant to C++. C and modern C++ are very different languages these days.

Comment: i dont know the book, but I think it is not called "The art of printing Hello World" for a reason. I would expect it to be about exploiting stuff like out-of-bounds and apparently they succesfully did so on your pc :P

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. Thank you for the help, everyone! Its odd, though - the example was only supposed to show how to use input and output functions in C, it wasn't supposed to show any exploits, so I guess it was an oversight by the author. I also checked the char array by printf-ing it after the strcpy line, but as John said - if nothing was clobbered, it looks like it's functioning normally!

Comment: I don't know that book but from that title I would expect that it not only contains broken code, but also explains how and why it is broken. The interesting part seems to be missing....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char message[10];
...
strcpy(message, "Hello, world!");
```

`message` cannot contain the whole `Hello, world!` because it is to small. You're thus running into undefined behaviour, which explains the strange output you are seeing. You need to increase the size of `message` or determine its required size dynamically, e.g. using `strlen`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the length of the message buffer. The string "Hello, world!" contains 13 characters + 1 for `\0` that strcpy add automatically, so the final length is 14. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char message[14];
    int count, i;

    strcpy(message, "Hello, world!");

    printf("Repeat how many times? ");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    for(i=0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%3d - %s\n", i, message);
}
```

Hint: is better use strnlen instead of strlen.